# How to print to Android Studio Logcat from (fork of) Third Party Library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently working with a fork of a third party library for Android and would like to print some information to the Android Studio console (Logcat). Normally you can simply call something like:

```
Log.i("mytag", "my message here");
```

But this doesn't seem to work when calling from a library. Does anyone know how to go about printing to the Android Studio Logcat Console from a library? Any tips or hints pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks

UPDATE: This is a native Java/Android library for React-Native. The library I'm working with is a fork of react-native-webview. I don't know if any of that information is particularly important, but for context I thought I should mention the specifics of what I'm working with.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘this doesn't seem to work’?

Comment: how about posting what have you tried, e.g. the logs that don't show up? also, are you testing it on emulator or a real device? Some devices have logs turned off for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to do it if the default one is not working for you. The one is to use either custom [`Logger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger) or use automatically created via this class static factories

[`Logger.getLogger(String name, String localizationBundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger#getLogger(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

or

[`Logger.getLogger(String name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger#getLogger(java.lang.String))).

And then use its [`log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger#log(java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.String)) method which has a lot of overloads for the variety of cases. Its usage is pretty straightforward:

```
// usual name for the logger is the name of the main class of the library

private val logger = Logger.getLogger(MyLibraryMainClass::class.java.name)
logger.log(logLevel, message) //where logLevel is Level.WARNING or Level.INFO etc..
```

Also [Log.println(int priority, String tag, String msg)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#println(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) may work.

Also try checking the settings of your logcat - it may be misconfigured. You may try to do it via [adb logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) command also.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a native library (C, C++). If so, you can follow a similar approach as someone writing a android NDK library can follow. You need to include

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

Then you will be able to access the `__android_log_print`  method to print the log statement. You should be able to see this statement in the logcat with the tag. This is the prototype:

```
int __android_log_print(int prio, const char *tag,  const char *fmt, ...);
```

More details are here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging

An example would be:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT, "Your library tag", "Your log statement");
```

Comment: No, it's a Java library. Specifically, it's a fork of a Java/Android library for React-Native: react-native-webview